# The Cantor staircase function and related things

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

The Cantor staircase function 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function
has an interesting property: $\{x\colon f'(x)\neq 0\}$ is a nowheredense nullset.
But it it differentiable almost everywhere, not everywhere.
Hence my question is if nondecreasing nonconstant differentiable function can have the above property?

Comment: A constant function would have that property.

Comment: Your notation is a bit off: $\{ x : f'(x) \neq 0 \text{ or does not exist } \}$ is $C$. What you actually wrote winds up being just $\emptyset$, and presumably the interesting property is that the set of interest is nowhere dense, null, and *nonempty*. Anyway, perhaps $d(x,C)^2$ will do the job?

Comment: Yes, I added that I'm interested in nondecreasing nonconstant function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem (Goldowski-Tonelli):** If $f$ is a real function on an interval that is differentiable *everywhere* (where "differentiable" means the derivative exists and is finite) and such that $f'\geq 0$ *almost everywhere* then, in fact, $f$ is nondecreasing (and by applying the same to $-f$ we get the immediate corollary: if $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'=0$ almost everywhere then, in fact, $f$ is constant).

This result is not trivial.  It was proven in 1928 and 1930 by Goldowski and Tonelli independently.  The hypotheses can be weakened slightly: it is enough for $f$ to be (a) continuous everywhere, (b) differentiable on the complement of a denumerable set, and (c) have nonnegative (resp. zero for the corollary) derivative almost everywhere.  Cantor's devil staircaise shows that (b) cannot be weakened to "differentiable almost everywhere".

A (modern) proof of the Goldowski-Tonelli theorem can be found in the paper "On Positive Derivatives and Monotonicity" by Stephen Casey and Richard Holzsager (*Missouri J. Math* **17** (2005), 161–173), [available here](http://cs.ucmo.edu/~mjms/2005.3/Casey-Holzsager.pdf).  Many related theorems are stated (and sometimes proved) in Andrew Bruckner's classic book *Differentiation of Real Functions* (AMS 1994).

The following examples is also worth thinking about: let $r_n$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$.  Let $a_n$ be sequence of positive reals with finite sum.  Then $f(x) := \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n (x-r_n)^{1/3}$ is a continuous increasing function which is differentiable everywhere except on the rationals where it has $+\infty$ derivative (in the obvious sense).  So the inverse bijection of $f$ is continuous, increasing, differentiable everywhere, and its derivative vanishes on a dense set.  (The derivatives of such functions are called "Pompeiu derivatives".)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mean everywhere differentiable.  The mean value theorem tells us that if $a\ne b$ then for some $c$ between $a$ and $b$ we have
$$
\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} = f'(c).
$$
If you further insist that $f'$ be $0$ everywhere, then you have $f'(c)=0$, and you can quickly deduce that $f(a)=f(b)$.  Since this applies to ALL possible values of $a$ and $b$, you conclude that $f$ is constant.

All of the above of course depends on the domain of $f$ being a set to which the mean value theorem can be applied, i.e. an interval.

Comment: The way I understand it, OP was asking whether a nondecreasing nonconstant everywhere differentiable function can have derivative zero *almost* everywhere.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen : It said "nondecreasing nonconstant differentiable function". $\qquad$

Comment: Exactly.  Nondecreasing, nonconstant, differentiable (everywhere), and having "the above property", where "the above property" was having derivative zero *almost* everywhere ($\{x:f'(x)\neq 0\}$ is a nullset).